# Как в Sublime Text сделать множественную замену?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text

Русскую букву `о` мне нужно заменить на `{о|o}`, русскую букву `а` на `{a|a}` и так далее, список большой. Возможно ли это средствами Sublime Text?

Comment: Можно написать на Sublime Text скрипт-программу, например на js, который будет искать и заменять перебором в тексте эти символы =D
А если серьезно, то сомневаюсь, что это удастся решить "малой кровью"

Comment: @СашаЧерных, ответ готов :)

Comment: @сашачерных это дубликат вопроса или эту задачу тоже необходимо решить?

Answer (score 3):

Есть подозрение, что данная задача является дубликатом.
Регулярное выражение для замены ровно то же как и в этом ответе:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512787/481
но строка замены:

```
{$1|$2}
```

В ссылке выше подробно расписано как сделать подобную замену одним регулярным выражением в один проход.

Comment: В том, на что заменить одна буква английская, а одна русская. Так что не то. Хотя, я не очень понял, а что там надо.

Comment: @Qwertiy, у автора вопроса [в первом случае кириллица/латиница, во втором латиница/латиница](http://pokit.org/get/?b396027af6eb598b55e491aef2c77f32.jpg), где опечатался — ему одному известно.// Мне решение второго варианта интересно было бы узнать, где кириллические символы заменялись бы на латинские, с которыми имеют одинаковое написание: с (эс) на c (це), x (ха) на x (икс) и т. д. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, а для NPP с двумя дополнительными заменами пойдёт? Или как в прошлый раз?

Comment: @Qwertiy, каковы различия у регулярных выражений в Sublime Text и Notepad++ ? Ведь [в обоих](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) [используются](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html) Perl Compatible Regular Expressions.// Да, и, может, для Sublime Text уже есть решение, подобное плагину [Mimic](https://nix.dirty.ru/mimic-utilita-dlia-podmeny-pokhozhikh-simvolov-870582/) у Vim? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, думаю, никаких :) Просто [в тот раз](/a/498787/178988) формат текста оказался несоответствующим вопросу ;)

Comment: @ReinRaus _"Данную задачу нельзя решить регулярными выражениями"_ - если использовать больше одной замены, то можно. См. мой ответ - в 3 замены делается. Я сделал в 4, чтобы не писать одну регулярку руками.

Comment: @Qwertiy, где-то есть разница, знать бы, в чём она. Например, мне понадобилось удалить пустые строчки. Регулярное выражение [`\n\r`](http://cmsuser.ru/2013/03/30/kak-udalit-pustye-stroki-v-notepad.html) , применимое для Notepad++  , не работает на Sublime Text. А подошло [`^\n`](http://blogo-daru.ru/2015/10/07/kak-udalit-pustye-strochki-v-kode-napisannom-v-sublimetext/) . Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Делаю в Notepad++.
Включена замена с регулярными выражениями, новые строки отключены.
Отмечен флажок Учитывать регистр.

## Начальный текст

```
БЭМ в том числе ориентировался на максимизацию производительности.
Один класс - это очень быстро. Один тег - тоже.
А вот атрибуты - это уже гораздо медленее.

А так, по самой идеологии проблем не вижу.

Ещё по поводу валидности разметки - кастомные теги должны содержать дефис.
```

## Замена 1

Добавляем в конец всех строк посторонние символы, которые мы собираемся вставить  в замене в зависимости от найденных:

```
$
aeocrAEOCM
```

```
БЭМ в том числе ориентировался на максимизацию производительности.aeocrAEOCM
Один класс - это очень быстро. Один тег - тоже.aeocrAEOCM
А вот атрибуты - это уже гораздо медленее.aeocrAEOCM
aeocrAEOCM
А так, по самой идеологии проблем не вижу.aeocrAEOCM
aeocrAEOCM
Ещё по поводу валидности разметки - кастомные теги должны содержать дефис.aeocrAEOCM
```

## Упрощающий шаг

Создаём новый документ со следующим содержимым:

```
аеосгАЕОСМaeocrAEOCM
```

В нём выполняем замену

```
(.)(?=.{9}(.))
$1\(?=.*\($2\)\)|
```

Результат:

```
а(?=.*(a))|е(?=.*(e))|о(?=.*(o))|с(?=.*(c))|г(?=.*(r))|А(?=.*(A))|Е(?=.*(E))|О(?=.*(O))|С(?=.*(C))|М(?=.*(M))|aeocrAEOCM
```

## Замена 2

Собственно выполняем нужную замену:

```
(?=а(?=.*(a))|е(?=.*(e))|о(?=.*(o))|с(?=.*(c))|г(?=.*(r))|А(?=.*(A))|Е(?=.*(E))|О(?=.*(O))|С(?=.*(C))|М(?=.*(M)))(.)
{$11|$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10}
```

```
БЭ{М|M} в т{о|o}м чи{с|c}л{е|e} {о|o}ри{е|e}нтир{о|o}в{а|a}л{с|c}я н{а|a} м{а|a}к{с|c}имиз{а|a}цию пр{о|o}изв{о|o}дит{е|e}льн{о|o}{с|c}ти.aeocrAEOCM
{О|O}дин кл{а|a}{с|c}{с|c} - эт{о|o} {о|o}ч{е|e}нь бы{с|c}тр{о|o}. {О|O}дин т{е|e}{г|r} - т{о|o}ж{е|e}.aeocrAEOCM
{А|A} в{о|o}т {а|a}трибуты - эт{о|o} уж{е|e} {г|r}{о|o}р{а|a}зд{о|o} м{е|e}дл{е|e}н{е|e}{е|e}.aeocrAEOCM
aeocrAEOCM
{А|A} т{а|a}к, п{о|o} {с|c}{а|a}м{о|o}й ид{е|e}{о|o}л{о|o}{г|r}ии пр{о|o}бл{е|e}м н{е|e} вижу.aeocrAEOCM
aeocrAEOCM
{Е|E}щё п{о|o} п{о|o}в{о|o}ду в{а|a}лидн{о|o}{с|c}ти р{а|a}зм{е|e}тки - к{а|a}{с|c}т{о|o}мны{е|e} т{е|e}{г|r}и д{о|o}лжны {с|c}{о|o}д{е|e}рж{а|a}ть д{е|e}фи{с|c}.aeocrAEOCM
```

## Замена 3

Удаляем хвосты с мусором, а именно, заменяем

```
aeocrAEOCM$
```

на пустоту. Не потерять знак `$` в конце.

Готово:

```
БЭ{М|M} в т{о|o}м чи{с|c}л{е|e} {о|o}ри{е|e}нтир{о|o}в{а|a}л{с|c}я н{а|a} м{а|a}к{с|c}имиз{а|a}цию пр{о|o}изв{о|o}дит{е|e}льн{о|o}{с|c}ти.
{О|O}дин кл{а|a}{с|c}{с|c} - эт{о|o} {о|o}ч{е|e}нь бы{с|c}тр{о|o}. {О|O}дин т{е|e}{г|r} - т{о|o}ж{е|e}.
{А|A} в{о|o}т {а|a}трибуты - эт{о|o} уж{е|e} {г|r}{о|o}р{а|a}зд{о|o} м{е|e}дл{е|e}н{е|e}{е|e}.

{А|A} т{а|a}к, п{о|o} {с|c}{а|a}м{о|o}й ид{е|e}{о|o}л{о|o}{г|r}ии пр{о|o}бл{е|e}м н{е|e} вижу.

{Е|E}щё п{о|o} п{о|o}в{о|o}ду в{а|a}лидн{о|o}{с|c}ти р{а|a}зм{е|e}тки - к{а|a}{с|c}т{о|o}мны{е|e} т{е|e}{г|r}и д{о|o}лжны {с|c}{о|o}д{е|e}рж{а|a}ть д{е|e}фи{с|c}.
```

Comment: Круть ) Редкостное извращение )

Comment: @ReinRaus, ага)))

Comment: Можно проще по образу и подобию: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512787/481