# Быстрая замена в тексте латинских символов на кириллические со сходным начертанием

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Здравствуйте. Приходится иметь дело с русскими текстами, где присутствует нежелательное вкрапление символов английского алфавита.

[image: Вкрапление латинских символов в Sublime Text]

Т. к. расположение вкраплений всегда разное и не подчинено каким-либо правилам, я не могу осуществлять поиск слов в тексте.

Решение — заменить латинские буквы `ABEKMHOPCTXaeopcyx` на соответствующие им кириллические `АВЕКМНОРСТХаеорсух`: `A` → `А`, `B` → `В` и т. д. Как в Sublime Text эффективнее всего произвести все 18 замен?

Этот вопрос частный случай более общего: как произвести множество замен в одном регулярном выражении? Спасибо.

Comment: sublime не поддерживает `?{}`, а значит код для подмены вставить не выйдет. Если Вы используете linux, то можно использовать команду [tr](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=tr&category=1), которая как раз и выполняет Вашу задачу.

Comment: Ну ведь [то же самое](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512105/178988)... Что мне теперь, ответ копипастить с минимальными изменениями?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Плагин для **ST2**, выполняющий желаемое:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class MultipleReplace(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        target   = "ABEKMHOPCTXaeopcyx" # en
        replacer = u"абекмнорстхАЕОРСУХ" # ru
        region = sublime.Region(0, self.view.size())
        fullText = unicode( self.view.substr( region ) )
        count = 0
        for ch in range( len(target) ):
            count += fullText.count( target[ch] )
            fullText = fullText.replace( target[ch], replacer[ch] )
        self.view.replace( edit, region, fullText )
        sublime.status_message( "Hidden chars replaced: " + str( count ) )
```

Плагин для **ST3**, выполняющий желаемое:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class MultipleReplace(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        target   = "ABEKMHOPCTXaeopcyx" # en
        replacer = u"абекмнорстхАЕОРСУХ" # ru
        region = sublime.Region(0, self.view.size())
        fullText = self.view.substr( region )
        count = 0
        for ch in range( len(target) ):
            count += fullText.count( target[ch] )
            fullText = fullText.replace( target[ch], replacer[ch] )
        self.view.replace( edit, region, fullText )
        sublime.status_message( "Hidden chars replaced: " + str( count ) )
```

Вечером распишу подробнее, как устанавливать плагины в ST.

---

Здесь можно найти, как устанавливать плагин:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/136529/

Comment: `Tools` → `New Plugin...` → скопипастил Ваш код → сохранил как `latin_to_cyrillic.py`. `Preferences` → `Key Bindings - User`, добавил строку `{ "keys": ["ctrl+j"], "command": "latin_to_cyrillic" },`. Пробовал подставлять различные горячие клавиши, `latin_to_cyrillic` везде написано латиницей. Однако не работает, консоль ничего не показывает. Где я ошибся? Спасибо.

Comment: у меня все начало работать только когда повесил на `ctrl+6` много комбинаций пробовал

Comment: К сожалению, ни одна комбинация не заработала ( . Вставил Вашу обновлённую версию плагина — всё равно ничего не выходит. Спасибо.

Comment: Видимо, не в горячих правилах проблема. Поставил Вашему плагину шорткат на `ctrl` + `l`, который у меня стоял на другом, работающем плагине. По-прежнему ничего не происходит при попытке запуска. Где я ещё мог ошибиться? Спасибо.

Comment: Наверно надо тогда переименовать класс в `LatinToCyrillic`, я переименовал и заработало. Перед этим сохранил в UTF-8 без BOM. Хз- нужно ли это. Попробуйте сначала просто переименовать.

Comment: Переименовал (до того, как оставить первый комментарий к данному  треду, уже переименовывал в `latin`) — ничего не изменилось.// > Перед этим сохранил в UTF-8 без BOM — `UTF-8` или `UTF-8 with BOM`? Правда, у меня в обоих случаях не заработало.

Comment: А как запускается плагин? Открываю `.txt` или `.log` файл → ставлю ему кодировку `UTF-8`, если та ещё не установлена, → нажимаю на горячие клавиши. Или что-то другое небходимо проделывать? Да, добавил плагин в контекстное меню, но на пункт, соответствующий `LatinToCyrillic` [**не нажать**](https://i.gyazo.com/b4e8b211d1e26c7ecc697b098a981822.png). Спасибо.

Comment: Может Вы не туда смотрите? Попробуйте заменить `status_message` на `error_message`. Статусное сообщение внизу слева.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38532/discussion-between---and-reinraus).

Answer (score 2):

**Just for fun**

Все это можно сделать регулярным выражением в один проход, но рекомендую плагин все же. Плагин - это правильный путь решения задачи.

**Итак**

- Добавляем в конец текста с новой строки "магическую" строку (в ней чередуются латинский символ и соответствующий киррилический)

  ```
  AАBВEЕKКMМHНOОPРCСTТXХaаeеoоpрcсyуxх
  ```
- Ищем по регулярному выражению

  ```
  (.)(?=[\s\S]*\n[^\n]*\1(.)(?:[^\n]{2})*\n?(?![\s\S]))
  ```
- с учетом регистра
- замену делаем на

  ```
  $2
  ```
- удаляем "магическую" строку из текста

Потрогать регулярку можно здесь:
https://regex101.com/r/iW2yE3/1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Круто! Но жутко неэффективно. Я не использовал многострочный режим именно из-за эффективности.

Comment: @Qwertiy в Вашем варианте человек - крайне неэффективное и малопроизводительное звено :)

Comment: А если файл на несколько мегабайт?)))

Comment: `Плагин - это правильный путь решения задачи` :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, [на 89](http://pokit.org/get/img/ab7e1a5b89bac6039bb022a051d2ac93.jpg)...

Answer (score 1):

### К сведению

1. Нативный поиск <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> Sublime Text 3 позволяет вести множественный поиск. Синтаксис поисковых запросов: `($первая фраза|$вторая фраза)`.

[image: Тонкий худи]

Однако сделать множественную замену одним запросом в нативном поиске не получится.

2. Решение, расписанное в данном ответе, позволяет делать множественные замены только в одном файле, но не нескольких. Не скажу, что очень уж тщательно искал, но мне вообще не удалось найти любых программ (искал для своей ОС — Windows), при помощи которых можно было бы делать множественные замены во множестве файлов.
3. Протестировано в ноябре 2016 на Sublime Text Build 3126. Упреждаю, поскольку, например, настройки, описанные в [**статье о RegReplace за июнь 2016**](https://css-tricks.com/run-multiple-find-replace-commands-sublime-text/) уже утратили актуальность.

---

---

### RegReplace

[**Плагин**](https://github.com/facelessuser/RegReplace), служащий для выполнения множественных замен в Sublime Text 3, [**документация**](http://facelessuser.github.io/RegReplace/). Позволяет заменять не только в простых случаях, как рассматриваемый в данном вопросе, но и с использованием регулярных выражений, для операций с которыми используется [**модуль Python `re`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

---

---

### Составление правил замены в RegReplace

`Preferences` → `Package Settings` → `RegReplace` → `Rules - User` → в открывшийся файл вставляем код.

```json
{
    "replacements":
    {
       "sasha_felicity_A":
        {
            "find": "A",
            "replace": "А",
        },
        "sasha_felicity_B":
        {
            "find": "B",
            "replace": "В",
        },
       "sasha_felicity_E":
        {
            "find": "E",
            "replace": "Е",
        },
        "sasha_felicity_K":
        {
            "find": "K",
            "replace": "К",
        },
        "sasha_felicity_M":
        {
            "find": "M",
            "replace": "М",
        },
        "sasha_felicity_H":
        {
            "find": "H",
            "replace": "Н",
        },
        "sasha_felicity_O":
        {
            "find": "O",
            "replace": "О",
        },
        "sasha_felicity_P":
        {
            "find": "P",
            "replace": "Р",
        },
        "sasha_felicity_C":
        {
            "find": "C",
            "replace": "С",
        },
        "sasha_felicity_T":
        {
            "find": "T",
            "replace": "Т",
        },
        "sasha_felicity_a":
        {
            "find": "a",
            "replace": "а",
        },
        "sasha_felicity_e":
        {
            "find": "e",
            "replace": "е",
        },
        "sasha_felicity_o":
        {
            "find": "o",
            "replace": "о",
        },
        "sasha_felicity_p":
        {
            "find": "p",
            "replace": "р",
        },
        "sasha_felicity_c":
        {
            "find": "c",
            "replace": "с",
        },
        "sasha_felicity_y":
        {
            "find": "y",
            "replace": "у",
        },
        "sasha_felicity_x":
        {
            "find": "x",
            "replace": "х",
        },
    }
}
```

Напротив `find` латинские символы, напротив `replace` — кириллические. Вместо `sasha_felicity_$буква` можете назвать правила любыми другими именами, лишь бы они не совпадали с названиями других правил.

Если не указать флага [**IGNORECASE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500864/case-insensitive-python-regular-expression-without-re-compile/10444271#10444271), то при выполнении операций поиска и замены будет учитываться регистр. Латинская `H` в тексте заменится на кириллическую `Н`, но латинская `h` не сменится кириллической `н`, что и нужно по условиям вопроса. Если учитывать регистр надо, синтаксис правила будет таким:

```json
"sasha_felicity_H":
{
    "find": "(?i)H",
    "replace": "Н",
},
```

---

---

### Запуск команды с правилами RegReplace

Для работы с командами в Sublime Text я использую фрэймворк [**Suricate**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Suricate). Он позволяет не создавать 100500 файлов `sublimе-commands`, `sublime-keymap`, `Context.sublime-menu` и `Main.sublime-menu`, а задать настройки для открытия команд из Command Palette, контекстного меню, Menu Bar и горячими клавишами в одном файле сразу для всех команд всех плагинов и настроек по умолчанию.

- [**Страница документации Suricate о командах**](https://sublime-suricate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-guide/#commands),
- [**Как настроить запуск команд в Suricate**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587973/199934).

В файл `User/Default.suricate-profile` добавляем следующие строки:

```json
"sublime_latin_to_cyrillic":
{
    "call": "sublime.reg_replace",
    "caption": "RegReplace: Latin To Cyrillic",
    "args": {
      "replacements": [
        "sasha_felicity_A",
        "sasha_felicity_B",
        "sasha_felicity_E",
        "sasha_felicity_K",
        "sasha_felicity_M",
        "sasha_felicity_H",
        "sasha_felicity_O",
        "sasha_felicity_P",
        "sasha_felicity_C",
        "sasha_felicity_T",
        "sasha_felicity_a",
        "sasha_felicity_e",
        "sasha_felicity_o",
        "sasha_felicity_p",
        "sasha_felicity_c",
        "sasha_felicity_y",
        "sasha_felicity_x",
      ]
    }
},
```

Параметры:

- `sublime_latin_to_cyrillic` — имя массива. Можете задать произвольное, лишь бы самим было понятно, что оно означает.
- `call` — название команды Sublime Text в формате `sublime.$имя команды`.
- `caption` — как будет называться пункт в Command Palette, нажав на который запустится команда, прописанная в `call`. Вместо `RegReplace: Latin To Cyrillic` Можете задать произвольное, лишь бы самим было понятно, что оно означает.
- `args` — аргументы команды `reg_replace`. В их качестве выступают правила, о которых шла речь в предыдущем разделе.

я рекомендую использовать Suricate, но можете задать настройки и без установки дополнительных плагинов. `Preferences` → `Package Settings` → `RegReplace` → `Commands - User` → в открывшийся файл вставляем код:

```json
[
    {
      "caption": "Reg Replace: Test RegReplace",
      "command": "reg_replace",
      "args": {
        "replacements": [
            "sasha_felicity_A",
            "sasha_felicity_B",
            "sasha_felicity_E",
            "sasha_felicity_K",
            "sasha_felicity_M",
            "sasha_felicity_H",
            "sasha_felicity_O",
            "sasha_felicity_P",
            "sasha_felicity_C",
            "sasha_felicity_T",
            "sasha_felicity_a",
            "sasha_felicity_e",
            "sasha_felicity_o",
            "sasha_felicity_p",
            "sasha_felicity_c",
            "sasha_felicity_y",
            "sasha_felicity_x",
        ]
      }
    }
]
```

Что означают параметры, понятно из предыдущего раздела. Не путайтесь в [**JSON-синтаксисе**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/238934/199934) конфигурационных файлов, правильно расставляйте скобки, кавычки и запятые.

---

---

### Использование

После того, как произвели все настройки, открываем файл, в котором необходимо произвести замену, → <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `Suricate: RegReplace: Latin To Cyrillic` → <kbd>Enter</kbd> → должно получиться так:

[image: Ришта Морра]