# Как выделить текст между парными "кавычками" в Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Как выделить текст между двумя парными "кавычками" в Sublime Text 3?

Есть [горячие клавиши](http://sublimetext.ru/documentation/hotkeys/windows), но там присутствует только метод выделения текста между скобками (brackets) или парными тегами.

Изменение стандартной комбинации на свою не помогает:

```html
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+m"], "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "brackets"} }
```

Comment: Устанавливаете плагин https://github.com/kek/sublime-expand-selection-to-quotes → `Preferences` → `Key Bindings - User` → добавляете строки `// Выделение текста между кавычками
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+alt+'"],
        "command": "expand_selection_to_quotes"
    },`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 0. Не рекомендуется

---

### 1. Expand Selection to Scope

Встроенное в Sublime Text средство выделения, упомянутое в [**ответе**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/566775/199934) ув-мого Виталия Емельянцева.

#### 1. Демонстрация

Во всех примерах выделяется текст не только между кавычек, но и сами кавычки.

[image: Expand Selection to Scope]

#### 2. Ожидаемое поведение

мне не удалось найти документации по команде `expand_selection` с аргументом `{"to": "scope"}`, но, исходя из названия и некоторых характеристик поведения, должен выделяться весь текст рядом с кареткой, имеющий ту же [**scope**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516668/199934), что и символ перед кареткой.

Scope в Sublime Text могут быть достаточно длинными, например: `text.html.basic source.js.embedded.html meta.delimiter.comma.js, text.html.basic source.js.embedded.html meta.function.declaration.js punctuation.separator.parameter.function.js`. Expand Selection To Scope должно выделить сначала `text.html.basic source.js.embedded.html meta.delimiter.comma.js, text.html.basic source.js.embedded.html meta.function.declaration.js punctuation.separator.parameter.function.js`, затем, если рядом есть такая область видимости, — `text.html.basic source.js.embedded.html meta.delimiter.comma.js, text.html.basic source.js.embedded.html meta.function.declaration.js`, потом `text.html.basic source.js.embedded.html meta.delimiter.comma.js, text.html.basic source.js.embedded.html` и т. д.

В первом примере на демо кавычки в синтаксисе для [**Suricate**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587973/199934) имеют ту же область видимости, что и текст меж ними; во втором — кавычки включены в комментарий, поэтому выделяется комментарий, а не текст между кавычками. Это ожидаемое поведение.

Команда `expand_selection` с аргументом `{"to": "scope"}` и должна выделять текст по scopes, а не [**делимитерам**](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/delimite.htm). Кавычки в различных синтаксисах имеют собственные области видимости далеко не всегда, поэтому когда работаете с различными синтаксисами, лучше не пользоваться ей для выделения текста между кавычками.

#### 3. Актуальное поведение

Судя по последним двум выделениям на демо **Expand Selection to Scope имеет баги**, воспроизводящиеся на «чистом» Sublime Text без плагинов и пользовательских настроек.

В третьем и четвёртом примерах по идее должен выделяться текст между кавычек. В третьем `expand_selection {"to": "scope"}` выделяет кавычки во встроенном в HTML скрипте, в четвёртом на синтаксисе пакета [**PackageDev**](https://github.com/SublimeText/PackageDev) вообще предлагает крайне нерелевантные выделения.

---

### 2. [**Keyboard Selection**](https://github.com/robertcollier4/KeyboardSelectionSublime)

#### 1. Демонстрация

[image: Keyboard Selection]

#### 2. Описание

Данный плагин позволяет выделять текст между различными типами кавычек, скобок и между различными [**делимитерами**](https://github.com/robertcollier4/KeyboardSelectionSublime#key-bindings). Только, как видно из GIF, он выделяет текст между одинарной кавычкой — `'` и двойной — `"`; между угловой скобкой — `<` и квадратной — `]`. Плагин не сопоставляет типы кавычек и скобок. Также я не понимаю, зачем на практике может понадобиться выделение между различными делимитерами.

Остальные команды плагина во многом идентичны дефолтным командам Sublime Text, в Windows запускающимися шорткатами <kbd>Ctrl+Left/Right</kbd>, <kbd>Alt+Left/Right</kbd> и <kbd>Ctrl+Delete</kbd>. В целом не вижу, зачем может пригодиться Keyboard Selection.

---

---

## 1. Плагины специально для выделения текста между кавычками

В книге «Sublime Text Power User» упомянуты 2 плагина, отвечающие на данный вопрос: [**Select Quoted**](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/Kristinita/SashaBooks/blob/master/IT/Sublime%20Text/Sublime%20Text%20Power%20User.pdf#page=100) и [**Expand Selection To Quotes**](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/Kristinita/SashaBooks/blob/master/IT/Sublime%20Text/Sublime%20Text%20Power%20User.pdf#page=198).

---

### 1. [**SelectQuoted**](https://github.com/int3h/SublimeSelectQuoted)

При нажатии шортката — <kbd>Ctrl+'</kbd> по умолчанию в Windows — выделяется сначала текст между кавычек, затем вместе с кавычками, → но потом выделение останавливается.

[image: Select Quoted]

Вторая команда с аргументом `"args": {"inside": false}` — <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+'</kbd> по умолчанию в Windows — у меня [**не работает вообще**](https://github.com/int3h/SublimeSelectQuoted/issues/11).

---

### 2. [**Expand Selection To Quotes**](https://github.com/kek/sublime-expand-selection-to-quotes)

[image: Expand Selection To Quotes]

При нажатии шортката — <kbd>Ctrl+'</kbd> по умолчанию в Windows — выделяется сначала текст между кавычек, затем вместе с кавычками → потом между следующими кавычками и т. д.

---

---

## 2. Универсальные решения

Текст между определёнными делимитерами выделяет и [**Bracketeer**](https://github.com/colinta/SublimeBracketeer). Однако он не включён в данный обзор, поскольку из описаний автора плагина — ув-мого Colinta — по крайней мере лично мне проблематично понимать, для чего нужны его плагины и как они работают. Если хотите попробовать — упреждаю, что из приведённого в качестве примера [**кеймапа**](https://github.com/colinta/SublimeBracketeer/blob/master/Example.sublime-keymap) ничего не будет функционировать.

---

### 1. [**ExpandRegion**](https://github.com/aronwoost/sublime-expand-region)

#### 1. Демонстрация

[image: ExpandRegion]

#### 2. Описание

«Умное» выделение текста. Причём для любых видов выделений нужно нажимать всего один шорткат. Второй служит для возврата (undo) к предыдущему выделению (см. демо для Markdown). Поддерживаемые синтаксисы: HTML, Python, JavaScript, LaTeX.

Чтобы произвести выделение именно между кавычками, обычно приходится нажимать на хоткей 2 или более раз. Если нужны выделения исключительно между "кавычками", обратите внимание на решение 1.1, а лучше 1.2.

#### 3. Настройка горячих клавиш

После установки плагина хоткеи придётся задавать самим.

> Пользователям Windows не рекомендую копировать горячие клавиши, [**приведённые в описании**](https://github.com/aronwoost/sublime-expand-region#using) плагина. Они конфликтуют с глобальными шорткатами Windows, которые проблематично отключить, не получая багов. Если знаете, как отвязать отдельные горячие клавиши Windows, чтобы использовать их в Sublime Text, поделитесь решением с другими пользователями, ответив на [**соответствующий вопрос в Super User**](https://superuser.com/q/1147517/572069).

Как пользоваться Suricate, и что означает код ниже, читаем [**здесь**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/586841/199934). В файл `User/Default.suricate-profile` добавляем следующие строки:

```json
// Expand Region
"sasha_expand_region": {
    "caption": "Expand Region",
    "keys": ["super+y"],
    "call": "sublime.expand_region",
},
// Expand Region Undo
"sasha_expand_region_undo": {
    "caption": "Expand Region Undo",
    "keys": ["super+shift+y"],
    "call": "sublime.expand_region",
    "args": {
        "undo": true
        },
    "context": [{ "key": "expand_region_soft_undo" }]
},
```

- `context` — параметр, [**означающий, что команда выполняется только в определённом контексте**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html#contexts); в данном случае отмена выделения на предыдущее произведётся, если до того происходили выделения командой `expand_region`. Когда же мы ничего не выделяли хоткеем <kbd>Super+Y</kbd>, но нажали <kbd>Super+Shift+Y</kbd>, будет только напечатана буква `y` (если у Вас сочетанием <kbd>Super+Shift+Y</kbd> не настроен запуск других команд).

#### 4. Настройка синтаксиса

Выделение командой `expand_region` может не работать или функционировать плохо в отдельных синтаксисах. Например, у меня неважно выделялся текст для CSS во встроенном HTML и в Markdown-разметке. Чтобы исправить это, установите плагин [**Edit Preferences**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Preferences%20Editor) → `Edit Preferences: Edit Settings...` → `ExpandRegion` → `scope_selectors` → между фигурными скобками вставляем следующий код:

```json
"python": ["text.html.markdown.gfm"], "javascript": ["source.css"]
```

`text.html.markdown.gfm` и `source.css` — области видимости синтаксиса, рассматриваемые в следующем подразделе. Пробуем выделять теперь. Если по-прежнему плохо, вместо параметра `python` подставляем `javascript`, `html` и `latex`; вместо `javascript`, соответственно `python`, `html` и `latex`. Останавливаемся на варианте, который выделяет лучше.

#### 5. Получение области видимости синтаксиса

Каждая [**область видимости**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516668/199934) начинается со [**scope selector**](https://manual.macromates.com/en/scope_selectors), одинакового для всех scope синтаксиса. К примеру, для синтаксиса Ruby по умолчанию этот scope selector — `source.rb`, для C++ — `source.c++`. я не нашёл в [**документации**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html) или поиском в Google, чтобы первый scope selector имел конкретное точное название, назовём его «областью видимости синтаксиса» или «syntax scope».

Чтобы получить syntax scope, нажмите <kbd>Ctrl+'</kbd> (машинописный обратный апостроф, символ расположен на той же клавише, где кириллическая «ё») → вводим в открывшееся поле код:

```python
view.scope_name(0).split()[0]
```

Между 'одинарными кавычками' получаем syntax scope, которая много где может пригодиться.

#### 6. Scope selectors для встроенных языков

Но во втором случае лучше, если бы правила выделения ExpandRegion для JavaScript применялись только в инлайновом CSS, но не остальной части HTML-документа, поскольку парсер `javascript` из ExpandRegion позволяет ограничивать действие параметра `javascript` из п. 2.1.4 [**селекторами областей видимости**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html#scopes) — «scope selectors». `"javascript": ["source.css"]` означает, что если в HTML где-либо содержатся области видимости, содержащие в названии `source.css`, то ExpandRegion задействует параметр `javascript`, нет — ExpandRegion выделяет по умолчанию (при условии, что не заданы значения прочим параметрам).

Области видимости инлайновых CSS и JavaScript содержат scope selector, являющийся «областью видимости синтаксиса», как если бы файл был бы открыт в синтаксисе встроенного языка. То есть: открываем css-файл и получаем syntax scope — `source.css`. Это `source.css` будет содержаться и в названиях областей видимости для инлайнового CSS, начинающихся на `text.html.basic source.css.embedded.html`. У JavaScript область видимости синтаксиса — `source.js`, scope инлайнового JavaScript начинаются на `text.html.basic source.js.embedded.html`.

---

---

### 3. Дополнительные ссылки

- [**О выделении различных участков текста/кода в неофициальной документации Sublime Text**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/editing/editing.html);
- [**Описание действия плагина ExpandRegion, основанного на расширении для Emacs, разработанном, в свою очередь, на основе Mathematica IDE**](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/syntax_tree_walk.html);
- [**Принципы именования областей видимости в Sublime Text**](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/scope_naming.html).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте комбинацию `Ctrl+Shift+Space` - для некоторых форматов файлов она выделяет текст как раз внутри "кавычек". Точно работает в `.scss`, `.html`, а также в `.slim` для значений атрибутов тегов.

Comment: Указать неплохо было бы тогда, в каких именно файлах. Рекомендовать шорткат всё же не советовал бы. Вашим сочетанием вызывается достаточно широкая команда `expand_selection {"to": "scope"}`, не относящаяся именно к кавычкам. С помощью команды выделяется много чего, в частности, текст внутри самых разных скобок, кавычек, или вместе с ними. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы правы, поведение `Ctrl+Shift+Space` слишком зависит от контекста. Дополнил ответ форматами файлов. Оформите свой комментарий к вопросу в ответ - поставлю плюс.

Comment: HTML — http://i.imgur.com/coVWbAQ.gif

Comment: Виталий Емельянцев, ответил развёрнуто. Помнится, в обсуждении Вашего ответа были и другие комментарии...