# Как в sublime настройть билд исходя из расширения файла

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Нужно сделать так, чтобы `build system` устанавливался в зависимости от расширения файла. У меня есть 2 типа файлов `.jade` и `.scss`. Скачал расширение `SublimeBuildOnSave`, но видимо это не то, что мне надо

Comment: В Sublime Text можно ограничить действие Build System не расширением, а [**областью видимости**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516668/199934). Допустим, для jade — если пользуетесь плагином [**Jade**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Jade) — добавьте в свой `.sublime-build` файл строку `"selector": "test.jade",`. Как настроить автоматический выбор Build System, я расписал в [**этом ответе**](https://toster.ru/q/326804#answer_850517). Спасибо.

Comment: SublimeBuildOnSave — полезный плагин для тех, кто пользуется препроцессорами. После установки — и иногда настройки — для компиляции достаточно нажимать `Ctrl+S` в файле препроцессора, а не `Ctrl+S` и `Ctrl+B`, что экономит время. Спасибо.

Comment: Извиняюсь, опечатался в первом сообщении `"selector": "text.jade"`, а не `test`.

Comment: @сашачерных А насчет `scss`?

Comment: @саша  

    `{
 "cmd": ["jade", "$file", "--pretty"],
 "selector": "source.jade",
 "osx": {"path": "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"},
 "windows": {"shell": "true"}
    }` Вот мой `jade build`

Comment: Если пользуетесь синтаксисом [**SCSS**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SCSS), то `"selector": "source.scss",`.

Comment: @саша Оформите как ответ. Не понял. Какую `build system` ставить? Что если у меня несколько систем билда под `scss` (Развернутая и минифицированная). И кстати `jade` не подхватывает `jade build` когда сохраняешь или `ctrl`+`b`

Comment: @Hergott, // **1.** По SCSS: добавьте `"selector": "source.scss",` в оба файла Ваших Build System. При первом нажатии `Ctrl+B` будет предложено выбрать одну из двух Build System. Если понадобится вторая: `Ctrl+Shift+P` → `Build With: $Название Вашей второй Build System`. Так и переключайтесь между ними.

Comment: **2.** По Jade/Pug — Build System компилирует, если выбрать её вручную — `Tools` → `Build System` → `Jade`, и нажать `Ctrl+B`? Возможно, с установкой компонентов какие-то проблемы. // Область видимости точно `text.jade`? В зависимости от плагинов может быть разная. // Пробовали Build System [**проще**](https://addyosmani.com/blog/custom-sublime-text-build-systems-for-popular-tools-and-languages/) или плагин [**Jade Build**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Jade%20Build)? Спасибо.

Comment: [**В пункте 4.1.5**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544776/199934) я собрал некоторые полезные ссылки по Build System в Sublime Text. Может, пригодятся.

Comment: [**Пункт 2.5**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/593530/199934) посмотрите, как можно получить эти `text.jade` и `source.css`. Возможно, у Вас другие синтаксисы и, как следствие, не такие области видимости синтаксиса. Спасибо.