# пишу html код в sublime text 3. Копирую слово из тега <p> что бы вставить в тег <i>

Tags: html, html5, sublime-text-3

Пишу html-код в sublime text 3.

Копирую слово из тега `<p>`чтобы вставить в тег `<i>`. Однако, вставляется не одно слово, а весь путь с начала `<p>` и все что после него до точки. 
Причем само слово `consectetur`, которое я хотел вставить, не вставляется.

Ожидаемый результат:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <br> dolor <b>sit</b> , <i>consectetur<i> adipisicing elit.
```

Фактический результат:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <br> dolor <b>sit</b> , <i>
><p {

    >Lorem ipsum <br {

        > dolor <b {

            >sit</b {

                 , i adipisicing . , .</p {

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
</i> adipisicing elit. Et, possimus.</p>
```

Comment: суть вопроса то в чем?

Comment: Как вставить одно слово consectetur, вместо всего это пути, мне нужно  просто слово одно вставить,а не кучу эту)
может я как-то не верно изъясняюсь ?

Comment: должно выглядеть так 

<p>Lorem ipsum <br> dolor <b>sit</b> , <i>consectetur<i> adipisicing elit.

Comment: `может я как-то не верно изъясняюсь?` Угу, как-то ускользает суть происходящего. Что и куда вы вставляете, посредством чего? Попробуйте взглянуть на написанное вами глазами совершенно постороннего человека. Что конкретно вы делаете? Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V? Найти и заменить?

Comment: KoshtaPenthouse, правда плохо понятно( . У Вас, видимо, вопрос, который легче показать, чем объяснять на словах. я б на Вашем месте, скорее всего, снял бы GIF или видео, демонстрирующее что я делал. [**Программы, которые могут помочь Вам в этом**](http://alternativeto.net/software/screentogif/). Спасибо.

Comment: Тренируйтесь чётче выражать мысли в письменной форме, это всем непросто даётся. Но, пожалуйста, только не гифка и не видео! Не нужно прибегать к этим уродливым заменителям текста.

Comment: @СашаЧерных инженер должен уметь (или учиться) структурировать мысли и выражать их текстом, как на естественных языках, так и на языках программирования. Вы предлагаете изъясняться образами. Это более древняя, доязыковая форма общения. Она хороша для передачи эмоций, но не знаний.

Comment: Чуток переформатировал текст.

Comment: из текста в теге <p>Nol ru toronto</p> я выделяю слово "ru" и по средством "ctrl+x" вырезаю его, на его месте ставлю "i" и с помощью нажатия клавиши "tab" получаю тег <i></i>  и вставляю в него при помощи "ctrl+v" слово "ru" в место 
<p>Nol <i>ru</i> toronto</p>
 получаю 
<p>Nol <i>
><p {

 >Nol i toronto</p {

 }

}
</i> toronto</p>
". Сейчас лучше объяснил? или нет ?

Answer (score 2):

В целом процесс копипаста происходит довольно магически. 
Для начала нам необходимо определить кусок текста, который необходимо куда-то скопировать. Т.е. из `Ut non semper leo. Integer molestie elit volutpat pulvinar egestas. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam tristique faucibus leo non volutpat. Suspendisse dignissim leo at mauris ornare, eu posuere est aliquam. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras sodales sodales nisl. Suspendisse potenti.` Я выделяю мышкой только кусок `Nullam tristique faucibus leo non volutpat.`. текст при этом окрашивается в другой цвет. 
Далее очень внимательно: я нажимаю на клавиатуре комбинацию клавиш ctrl+c. Затем переходим в то место куда необходимо этот кусок вставить. Например, `<p></p>` . Тыкаю мышкой ровно посередине между тегами(выделенный кусок текста при этом теряет выделение и становится таким же как весь текст!!!), и нажимаю комбинацию клавиш ctrl+v, что бы получилось нечто `<p>Nullam tristique faucibus leo non volutpat.</p>`. Как правило, такая последовательность действий работает в 99% случаев. если я не ответил на ваш вопрос, напишите в комментариях где наши действия расходятся.

Comment: После тыкания мышкой между тегами, выделенный мной участок текста потерял свою окраску. Это нормально?

Comment: @vp_arth дельное замечание, пожалуй, достойно правки ответа!

Comment: Дмитрий, обратите внимание на пакет ExpandRegion — [**пункт 2.1**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/593530/199934). Возможно, это поможет Вам намного сократить время в сравнении с выделениями мышью. я нажимаю 1 или несколько раз на `Win+Y`, и практически всегда выделяется то, что нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: Это Sublime пытается копипастить с сохранением структуры?

Answer (score 0):

```
<b {

            >sit</b {

<b> {sit </b {
```

забыл закрыть тэг

Comment: не этого сейчас.

Comment: Чтобы код выглядел как код, добавьте четыре пробела перед каждой строкой. Либо выделите и нажмите Ctrl+K. ))