# Найти символ в строке, за исключением того, что находится в конце строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text-3

В окне редактора Sublime Text есть две строки:

```
011
011
```

Мне необходимо превратить это в:

```
0;1;1
0;1;1
```

Т.е. поставить точку с запятой после каждой цифры. **Если цифра стоит в конце строки, то после нее** `;` **не ставиться**.

Сейчас я делаю это в два такта:

1) *найти:* `(\d)` *заменить:* `$1;`
получаю:

```
0;1;1;
0;1;1;
```

2) Удаляю `;`, те что в конце — *найти:* `;$` *заменить:*

и получаю, то что хотел:

```
0;1;1
0;1;1
```

**Как мне сделать тоже самое, но одним регулярным выражением?**

Comment: [**При помощи пакета RegReplace**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/586841/199934) можно запускать сколько угодно регулярных выражений подряд одним хоткеем. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такие задачи можно эффективно решать используя механизм утверждений (Lookaround). В данном случае отлично подойдет отрицательное утверждение вперед ([Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead)):

```
/\d(?!$|\n)/
```

Не знаю, насколько это работает в Sublime, но вполне соответствует стандарту [PCRE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCRE).

А вот и [пример на regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9yf0y1/1).